# Change the "alpha","scale"and"depth" according to the y position of the MovieClip in Flash&AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i am making a interactive slideshow with all the image slide automatically at the beginning in the swf.

the first step is successful that i made all the MovieClip running just relative to the center of the circle,the code is here

```
var menu:Sprite = new Sprite();
menu.x = 275;
menu.y  =180;
menu.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveMenu);
addChild(menu);

var disX:Number = 200;
var disY:Number = 10;
var speed:Number = 0;

initMenu(3)

function initMenu(n:int){
      for(var i:int;i<n;i++){
         var mc:MovieClip = new IconMenu();
         mc.scaleX = mc.scaleY = .5;
         menu.addChild(mc);
       }

}

function moveMenu(e:Event):void{
    var iconCount = menu.numChildren;
    var depthArray:Array = new Array();
    var angle:Number = 360/iconCount;

    for(var z:int;z<iconCount;z++){
        var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(menu.getChildAt(z));
        mc.gotoAndStop(z+1);
        mc.x = cosD(speed+angle*z)*disX;
        mc.y = sinD(speed+angle*z)*disY;
    }
    speed+=2;

}
```

but after this i am not able to calculate the other value like "alpha","scale"and"depth" to make the slideshow more realistic

all the three value should be calculated according to the **`mc.y`**,since i think there should be a **Perspective effect**

and i am really new to Flash and Actionscript3 ,anyone could help me here?!

**really thanks a lot!**

Answer (score 0):

Hope that will help you.

---

**Alpha** & **Scale**:

Up -> Low
Down -> High

```
mc.alpha = mc.y / menu.height;

mc.scaleX = mc.scaleY = mc.y / menu.height;
```

Up -> High
Down -> Low

```
mc.alpha = 1 - mc.y / menu.height;

mc.scaleX = mc.scaleY = 1 - mc.y / menu.height;
```

---

**Depth**:

Up -> Behind
Down -> Front

```
for(var i:int = menu.numChildren - 1; i > -1; i--)
{
  var mc1:MovieClip = menu.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
  var mc2:MovieClip = menu.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;

  if(mc1.y < mc2.y)
  {
    if(menu.getChildIndex(mc1) > menu.getChildIndex(mc2))
    {
      menu.swapChildren(mc1, mc2);
    }
  }
}
```

Up -> Front
Down -> Behind

```
for(var i:int = menu.numChildren - 1; i > -1; i--)
{
  var mc1:MovieClip = menu.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
  var mc2:MovieClip = menu.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;

  if(mc1.y > mc2.y)
  {
    if(menu.getChildIndex(mc1) < menu.getChildIndex(mc2))
    {
      menu.swapChildren(mc1, mc2);
    }
  }
}
```